# how to schedule approval/Rejection workflow in aem?

Tags: workflow, scheduler, aem, activation

I have a requirement to develop approve-reject workflow. If user wants to approve the content he may schedule the activation by selecting date and time field from the review stage(workflow inbox), if he rejects the content an email notification should be sent to approver group and workflow initiator.

I used dialogue participant step to configure datetime field and approve group where approver can select the date.

How can I achieve the remaining functionality.

Is there any OOB functionality available.

Comment: SOF is not a free coding service. Please try to ask exact programming questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom [Process workflow step](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/extending/workflows.html) that uses the [Scheduler API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/org/apache/sling/commons/scheduler/Scheduler.html) to schedule a Sling [job](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/org/apache/sling/commons/scheduler/Job.html) at the timestamp that was chosen by the user in the participent step.

That Sling job can use the [Replicator API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/replication/Replicator.html) to replicate the approved content.